# NSArrayController bindings without Core Data

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I have an NSArrayController, the content of which I would like to be a list of the `CGDirectDisplayID`s of all of the connected Screens.  Right now I have the following code:

```
NSArray* screens = [NSScreen screens];
for (NSScreen* screen in screens)
{
    NSNumber* screenId = (NSNumber*)[[screen deviceDescription] valueForKey:@"NSScreenNumber"];
    [displaysList addObject:screenId];
}

[displaysArrayController setContent:displaysList];
```

displaysList is an NSMutable array which is allocated in `awakeFromNib`, what do I need to do in interface builder to populate a popup button with the values in `displaysList`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In the class with the code you posted above add a new NSArray property. Call it for
   instance displaysArray
2. Add a NSArrayController which you connect to the IBOutlet displaysArrayController
3. In the Interface Builder you'll find a group called "Object Controller"
   Set its mode to "NSArray"
   Disable the check "Prepares Content"
4. In another section you'll find a group called "Controller Content". Enable the checkbox and
   bind it to the object with the property displaysArray. Set the model key path to 
   displaysArray.

I hope that helps :)

Comment: Yes thank you.  Now when I have a UI element, say a popup button, what key path would I bind the Content Objects group to?

Comment: Bind it to the array controller and set the path to arranged objects

Comment: But if I just set the path to arranged objects then there is an error in the model key path saying it is expecting NSString and I'm giving it NSArray, how can I get it to pass the actual value in the array?

Comment: Add NSStrings instead of NSNumbers to your array